# Sublime Text 2 - Save Dialogue Tab Issues

Tags: macos, shortcut, text-editor, sublimetext

I've started using Sublime Text 2 on OS X and its great apart from one small thing.

I've enabled Tab to go through all controls:

[image: OS X Keyboard Shortcut Settings]

However, I cannot tab through on this dialogue that pops up when I try and close a window after making changes

[image]

Is there a fix to this or is this something that I'm going to have to open a thread on the forum?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are high you have the same keybinding active in Sublime.

Sublime Text uses a huge load of hotkeys/combinations and these are all defined in a simple textfile.

Go to "Menu/Sublime Text/Preferences/Key Bindings - Default", search for that combination and comment it out (or assign it to another hotkey).